# Eclipse product: how to clone the plugin version?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, version, clone, product

This may sound a bit strange, but i would rather avoid having to check the product version field each time i have to make an export.

Is there a way that the product version can be updated with the Plugin version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our headless build, our .product file product element has `version="0.9.0.@qualifier@"`.  Our *customTargets.xml* has a `<replace token="@qualifier@" ...` on the file before we call `p2.publish.product`.

A product export from the Product Configuration Editor seems to auto-update the qualifier in the .product file.

If you mean syncing the main part of the product version to a plugin in the product (like the product version 1.4.2 will match plugin X 1.4.2) I don't believe there's any support for that.

PW